# Excel-Drop down list that will change dynamically based on a criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

I want to create a drop down list that will change dynamically based on a criteria.

[image: example of the data]

In the column "Name" the same name can appear more than once. The "Option" value is unique.
Now based on the name placed in D1, I want a drop down list in cell E1 that will provide the user with all the "Options" whose name matches with the name in D1.

For example:
if D1="a" then the drop down list in E1 must have the options [1,4,7,10]
if D1="b" then the drop down list in E1 must have the options [2,5,8,11] etc

thank you all.

Comment: you will need to have helper columns that return the correct items for each Name, then using indirect with named ranges in the datavalidation.  There are many tutorials on how to do this:  https://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? We're not an Excel sheet writing service...

Comment: This needs an array CSE formula driven Drop down,, please check my post's list in past I've solved a few such issues!!

Comment: @spikey_richie I didn't have access to any pc that's why my answer is late. Anyway what I can do is: 
-create an array in a helper column with all the matches for each name
-create an a dynamic drop down list using the array from the helper array using the formula: 
=OFFSET($I$2;0;0;COUNTA($I:$I);1)  where I is the helper array

what I can not do is merge those two in one so that it becomes more automatic.
with my way I have to create the helper array for each option and I have more than 500 names so it will take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I tried my best to solve it. I have the file ready.

Actually, you need some helper columns to help the dropdown on cell E1. I've put the .xlsx file on Google Drive. [Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQ0xxngqL6XJ9N1FIkkF8mnI0lXoo-Q7/view) the file I've created with all the required helper columns. Just don't try to edit the view the file with Google Sheets, since there might be some functions in use which Google Sheets doesn't recognise. Download the file and open it with MS Excel.

The file looks like this:
[image: screenshot]

There is no VBA involved in this file. So you can just copy the formulas from here and create your own file too.

Here's how to use it: You enter any value which is in Column A, into D2. If you enter `a`, the dropdown automatically changes to showing all the corresponding "Options" which is in Column B, of all instances of `a`. And the dropdown updates dynamically if you enter `b` or `c` in D2.

But, There are some drawbacks to this.
There will some be extra blank options in the dropdown in E2. It's because I've created the function in J2 and all its cells such that, it automatically adds any new entries in A and B columns.
One more drawback is when you have a new name, like, `d`, you will have to enter `d` in cell M1, and you will have to select column L, drag the column over with the fill handle to column M and you will see all the corresponding "Options" of all instances of `d` in Column A.

The way it works is that it has this formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$200, SMALL(IF(J$1=$A$2:$A$200, ROW($A$2:$A$200)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"")` in cell J2. When you enter this formula in J2 and press CTRL+Shift+Enter, this ctrl+shift+enter combination creates an array formulae. It returns an array. If you just hit enter, it simply gives you an error or un-expected results. You can just drag the formula down to have see the whole return value. If you've dragged the formula down more than the number of results, the `IFERROR` function catches it and returns just an empty string instead of the error, so that you won't have errors in your dropdown and instead, you will have some blank options. The dropdown just uses a basic `OFFSET` function which looks like this `OFFSET($I$2,0,MATCH(D2,$J$1:$Z$1,0),10,1)`. This offset function also returns an array. It just searches the value of cell D2 in the first row from J1 through Z1. If D2 has the string `c`, it searches for c in `J1:Z1` and when it finds it, it gets how far it is from I2, and moves that many columns over, and selects 10 cells below it. These 10 cells are the things you get in the dropdown. If you have a lot of data, you might want to increase the number 10 to a bigger number and you might want to change J1:Z1 into something like J1:ZZ1.

Any problems regarding this file or the formulas,
you can just comment and I'll try my best to solve them.

Comment: We really don’t like answers that depend on external files.   Please [edit] your answer to describe how you created your file (formulas? VBA?).   And I’m not sure you really need the paragraph after the screen-shot, where you’re basically just describing the requirements in the question back to the asker.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, Since I was new, I didn't know I shouldn't have answers depending on external files. I have edited and gave an explanation of what's happening in the file.

Comment: Thanks for adding the details.

Comment: @SarveshM.D thank you for your response. As another member stated I never specified where exactly I was stuck.  We tried a similar approach.

 what I can do is: 
-create an array in a helper column with all the matches for each name basically in a similar way as you describe it
-create an a dynamic drop down list using the array from the helper array using the formula: 
=OFFSET($H$2;0;0;COUNTA($H:$H);1)  where H is the helper array. The drop down list stops in the first empty cell it will find.

Comment: what I can not do is merge those two in one so that it becomes more automatic.
With my way I have to create the helper array for each option and I have more than 500 names so it will take a lot of time. 
i was trying to find a formula I can put in the data validation source that can do the above two operations in one

However thank you again for your answer and time

Comment: @thomas_p You're welcome ! I'll try to do that automatically too.